# How to prove 2-EXP != EXP

Tags: complexity-theory

I am guessing that this is correct for `3-EXP`, `4-EXP` etc...

Basically I should find a problem in `2-EXP` that is not in `EXP`.
Any examples ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a direct consequence of the [time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem):

**Time Hierarchy Theorem**: if f and g are time-constructible functions and $f(n) \log f(n) =
o(g(n))$ (e.g. $f(n) = n^2, g(n) = n^3$), then $DTIME(f(n)) \subsetneq DTIME(g(n))$